# How to get text after string using reg expression in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
<p><b>Born:</b>333<br></p>
```

I try to get text `333` like as:

```
<b>Born:<\/b>(.)*<br>
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` is any character in a string, `*` means that we concern the repetition. Brackets determine a group to output.

You've used `(.)*` formula, what means that you will get only the last character (regex from your post should output `3`). If you want to output the whole expression `333`, try putting everything in one group using `(.*?)`.

Comment: It work but id I have line break or spaces beetwen `</b> HERE 333`

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression instead,

```
/<b>Born:<\/b>(.*?)<br>/
```

Here's an example,

```
$reg = "/<b>Born:<\/b>(.*?)<br>/";
$str = "<p><b>Born:</b>333<br></p>";
$matches = array();
preg_match($reg, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];  // 333
```

Here's the [**live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qB7rO4/1)

Comment: It work but id I have line break or spaces beetwen </b> HERE 333

Comment: @Dev *hmm*, in that case you need to specify `\s+` in your regular expression. I believe this would work for you, `/<b>Born:<\/b>\s+(.*?)<br>/`. Here's the live demo, [https://regex101.com/r/eF5pL0/1](https://regex101.com/r/eF5pL0/1).

Comment: So, `\s+` works wrong, beause when there is not space or break line, it does not work

Comment: @Dev Oh, I misunderstood your string format. Use `\s*` instead of `\s+`. The correct regular expression would be, `/<b>Born:<\/b>\s*(.*?)<br>/`. Here's the demo, [https://regex101.com/r/sW6oQ5/1](https://regex101.com/r/sW6oQ5/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<?php 
    $string     = "<p><b>Born:</b>333<br></p>";
    $extract    = preg_replace("#(<p>.*?<\/b>)(.*?)(<br.+>)#", "$2", $string);

    var_dump($extract); //<== DISPLAYS::: string '333' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid to parse html with regex since it's a bad practice (html has too many traps, you doesn't take advantage of the html structure and when html isn't well formatted the string approach stops to work). The way to go is to use a tool designed to parse html. The combo DOMDocument/DOMXPath is able to build a DOM tree and to query it using the XPath language:

```
$str = "<p><b>Born:</b> 333<br></p>";

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$xp = new DOMXPath(DOMDocument::loadHTML($str));
$result = $xp->evaluate('string(//b[.="Born:"]/following-sibling::text()[1])');

libxml_clear_errors();

echo trim($result);
```